# jQuery - KeyPress / KeyCode with enter to click button function

Tags: jquery, html

I am learning jQuery at the moment and have managed to get the below function to work for attaching a keyboard click of 'enter' to a button. Although I can't work out why I need to put anything in the function parameter or at the beginning of the if statement.

For example, why does this work:

```
$('#enter').keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            $('button').click();
        };
    });
```

And this doesn't:

```
$('#enter').keypress(function() {
        if(keyCode == 13) {
            $('button').click();
        };
    });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<input id="enter" placeholder="Enter text"></input>
<button>Get Info</button>
```

I am struggling to understand the significance of 'event' here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you are passing the [`event` object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to the function. When the event is triggered, `keyCode` is a property on the associated `event` object. If you don't pass the `event` object, you can't access the `keyCode` property, which is why your second example wasn't working.

---

As a side note, `input` elements don't have closing tags.

Change:

```
<input id="enter" placeholder="Enter text"></input>
```

to:

```
<input id="enter" placeholder="Enter text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think what is confusing me is that I can substitute anything for 'event' and it still works, for example, I could change the two occurrences of 'event' to 'apples' and it would still work.

Also, thanks for the heads up on the HTML :)

Comment: @Wub That's because you can name the parameter whatever you want (since you are passing it). It can be passed as `e`, `event`, etc.. and it will still be the same `event` object because that is the first parameter that is passed to the function when the event is triggered.

Comment: Also, in regards to your point about the HTML, should this be written without the trailing slash because I am using HTML5?

Comment: @Wub It's up to you. It is completely valid on 'void' element (such as `input`/`img` elements) and it will [validate in HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/2680216) with or without the trailing slash. It's just a personal preference. You will see the slash omitted sometimes. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag